# what happens to the data with a AJAX request/response if a page change happens in the middle

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, vb.net, asynchronous

Here is the expected simple scenario.

- On my page "page.aspx" jquery Ajax posts an instruction to getData.aspx in vb.net
- the Page_Load method in getData.aspx reads the instruction and goes to the Database then returns a lot of data as JSON to a string variable "myJson"
- then Context.Response.Write(myJason)
- then the  ajax reads the string that was made in getData.aspx

My question is, what happens to the data?

1. in the middle of the database fetch - where does the data go , the the vb function finish?
2. while the ajax is reading the Context.Response.Write(myJason)?

The data can't vanish into thin air?

If there is no exception and the Context.Response.Write("result") finishes in vb.net but ajax does not complete reading the response it's not used because the person refreshed the page, what happens to it?

In summary, what happens to the response if the page that requested it redirects. The response can't just vanish into thin air?

Thank you

Comment: If I understand you correctly (which I doubt) ... the data cannot be sent anywhere because the connection of the request is lost. So it will "vanish into thin air"

Comment: "What happens to the data ...". It's not clear what data you are referring to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What happens to the data
>
> in the middle of the database fetch - where does the data go , the the vb function finish?

Depends on what is in the vb function. The SQL query will most certainly complete. The process will fail (an exception will be raised) as soon as the server will try to send data to the client (which is not always during next Response.Write if Response is buffered)
All your data will be available for Garbage Collection

> while the ajax is reading the Context.Response.Write(myJason)?

Only part of the JSON content will be available on the client

> the data cant vanish into thin air?

Server-side, it will be garbage collected. So yes, it will vanish into thin air.

Comment: thank you for the reply - surely it cant just vanish into thin air - where would the response go - it must co some where? thank you

Comment: For data still on the server, it is dismissed and Garbage collected. Data already received by the client will depend on the client behaviour. Data "on the line" (the tiny part of data sent by the server but not yet received by the client) will be dismissed by the client upon arrival.